# How to power up the Eiffel Tower?

Tags: imaginary-range

In Square Enix's [*Imaginary Range*](http://imaginaryrange.wikia.com/wiki/Imaginary_Range_Wiki) for Android, I'm kind of a bit stuck in powering up the Eiffel Tower. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some pictures back is a poster you can catch and use that shows a rocket (it's on the side of a bus-station if I remember correctly). It's pretty much the same thing as transforming Ciela.

Comment: yeah i was looking for some other thing like a rocket(but not the poster). thanks! finished it already and i need moar ciela XD